# How to add <link> or <meta> tags to <head> with HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, html-agility-pack, dom

The [link](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/releases/view/44954#DownloadId=120935) to download documentation from http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com is returning an error and I can't figure this out by trying the code.

I'm trying to insert various tags into the `<head>` section of a HtmlDocument that I've loaded from a HTML string. The original issue I'm having is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223444/how-to-programmatically-load-a-html-document-in-order-to-add-to-the-documents-h).

Can somebody give me an idea of how to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: The documentation download link is working fine for me.

Comment: maybe it's our firewall.. I'll try from a different connection. Thanks

Comment: I downloaded it from a different connection, and now every page in the .chm file is returning "The page cannot be displayed"!!

Comment: Right-click on the file in Windows, view its properties, then click the `Unblock` button.

Answer (score 15):

Maybe a bit late :-) Suppose I have this `test.htm` Html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World!</title>
</head>
<body>
    Hello World
</body>
</html>
```

Here is how to add a LINK element underneath the HEAD element. You will not the semantics is very close to the System.Xml one, on purpose:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("test.htm");

HtmlNode head = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/head");

HtmlNode link = doc.CreateElement("link");
head.AppendChild(link);
link.SetAttributeValue("rel", "shortcut icon");
link.SetAttributeValue("href", "http://www.mysite.com/favicon.ico");
```

The result will be:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World!</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.mysite.com/favicon.ico"></head>
<body>
    Hello World
</body>
</html>
```